# zsh-bindings: noremap on vi mode

Tags: zsh, zshrc, zsh-zle

I want to bind 'dd' in the zsh's vicmd into something like 'ddi', If i use:

```
bindkey -M vicmd -s dd 'ddi'
```

It will give me this output:

```
zsh: string inserting another one too many times
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer already

```
function delete_then_insert(){
  zle kill-whole-line
  zle vi-insert
}

zle -N  delete_then_insert
bindkey -M vicmd dd delete_then_insert
```